# iCloud Container identifier not recognized after App Transfer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I moved to another country and had to create a new legal entity there. So, I also transferred my app from my old legal entity to the new one.

I cannot build my app on a device anymore because of the following errors:

```
An iCloud Container with Identifier 'iCloud.com.***' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

```
No profiles for 'com.***' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.***'.
```

My app implements iCloud container and App groups for the Watch and Widget versions. It seems that these two capabilities are not handled correctly after the transfer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remember that your containers identifiers are set in your developer account in Certificates, Indentifiers and Profiles. Your identifier is registered in the old entity. I don't now how to move an identifier. I suspect you will need Apple to help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I contacted Apple and hope they will be able to fix this.